# Does a Binance API for Swift (iOS) exist?

Tags: ios, swift, binance, binance-api-client

I want to make an iOS app that can read data from my Binance account. Anyone know if there is an API for this? If no, is there any other way to get the data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

So, [this](https://github.com/binance-exchange/BinanceApi) is a Binance Api I found. In the future, you should try to do more research before you ask a question.

Comment: Even though it wasn't a great question, I'm sure @hoddy would want an answer. Also, I don't yet have the ability to downvote, otherwise I would've done that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they have an API: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/#change-log. I have also found this package that could help you: https://github.com/dpyro/BinanceApi